# expected dimension of higher secant varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety and $\sigma_s(X)$ be the $s$-th secant variety of $X$. We say $\sigma_s(X)$ has *expected dimension* if $\text{dim}(\sigma_s(X))= \text{min}\{ s(\text{dim}(X))+(s-1), n \}$.
My question is why is this the 'expected dimension'.  Of course the dimension can't get beyond $n$, but were does the $s(\text{dim}(X))+(s-1)$ part come from? Every reference I see just says something like: By summing up parameters we get the expected dimension...
Any explenation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you briefly define what the s-th secant variety is?

Comment: the Zariski closure of the union of all linear spans of $s$ points in $X$

Comment: In that case, how many parameters do we need to define a point in the secant variety? We need to pick s points on X and to define a point on X requires dim X parameters so that's s(dim X) parameters but then we also need to specify a point on the linear span which requires s-1 parameters since it's projective of dim s-1.

Comment: @Asvin I see, that makes it more intuitive. But aren't we forgetting about the points that come through the Zariski closure? Not every point on the $s$-th secant variety has to lie on the linear span of $s$ points in $X$. I am not too familiar with the notion of counting dimensions with parameters, but couldn't a point that gets added through the closing require more parameters?

Comment: The point is that dimension is basically determined on any open set. Any closure can only add stuff of smaller dimension so we don't need to worry about it.